# Why is my Fluent Window title staying centered?

Tags: wpf, xaml, controltemplate, fluent-ribbon

I'm using the latest version of `Fluent.Ribbon`. I've been doing some styling, most of which requires completely replacing the Styles and ControlTemplates, but I've hit a snag. The title of my app is centered in the header bar and I can't get it to move to the left.

My visual tree looks like this:

```
MainWindow
  Grid
    Adorner
      Grid
        DockPanel
          PART_Icon
          PART_RibbonTitleBar
            Grid
              PART_HeaderHolder [ContentPresenter]
                TextBlock
              PART_ItemsContainer
              PART_QuickAccessToolbarHolder
```

I copied the current version of the `Fluent:RibbonTitleBar` ControlTemplate and Style into my override `xaml` for modification, but nothing I do makes any difference (yes it is loading my overriding styles.)

When I use the inspector tool in the app, the only elements I can highlight are the innermost `TextBlock`, which fits the text exactly with no stretch, and the `DockPanel` several levels above, which stretches the full window width. In the original window ControlTemplate, which you can [see here](https://github.com/fluentribbon/Fluent.Ribbon/blob/fb3bfd46baad4ef9f6ce1780b03d183333504598/Fluent.Ribbon/Themes/RibbonWindow.xaml#L45), The `RibbonTitleBar` is the last element of the `DockPanel` which has `LastChildFill` set. The `RibbonTitleBar` does have a RenderSize of the full width, but then the `Grid` below it has a RenderSize of `0,0`. Then `PART_HeaderHolder` inside that has a RenderSize that exactly covers the title text.

It doesn't seem to matter if I set `HorizontalAlignment` on various elements to `Left` or `Stretch`. I also tried changing the innermost `Grid` to other container types such as `DockPanel` and `StackPanel`. Nothing changes anything about the layout.

Here's my style overrides for the `RibbonTitleBar`. The only change I've made is that I moved the QuickAccessToolbar to the end and permanently collapsed it (if I try deleting it, the app crashes looking for it) and I tried defining some columns on the inner `Grid` to no avail.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Fluent:RibbonTitleBar}">
    <Setter Property="Template"
            Value="{DynamicResource RibbonTitleBarControlOverride}" />
    <Setter Property="Focusable"
            Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment"
            Value="Top" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment"
            Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Margin="-2,0"
                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                           Text="{Binding}"
                           TextWrapping="NoWrap"
                           TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<ControlTemplate x:Key="RibbonTitleBarControlOverride"
                 TargetType="{x:Type Fluent:RibbonTitleBar}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="0" x:Name="PART_HeaderHolder"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                          ContentSource="Header"
                          IsHitTestVisible="False" />

        <Fluent:RibbonContextualGroupsContainer Grid.Column="1" x:Name="PART_ItemsContainer"                                                    
                                                IsItemsHost="True" />

        <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_QuickAccessToolbarHolder"
                          ContentSource="QuickAccessToolBar" Visibility="Collapsed" />
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsCollapsed"
                 Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Visibility"
                    Value="Collapsed"
                    TargetName="PART_ItemsContainer" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="HideContextTabs"
                 Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Visibility"
                    Value="Collapsed"
                    TargetName="PART_ItemsContainer" />
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something (which could be the case) just add `TextAlignment="Left"` to your `TextBlock` since you have it stretching.

Comment: That doesn't work either. Despite the Stretch, it still has a RenderSize that only encompasses itself in the center, with a width of only 53px. Its immediate container element is similarly small.